# Pavement stage construction; reduction of Structual Properties

Tags: civil-engineering, design, highway-engineering

Which properties of flexible pavement layers are reduced (discounted) in a stage construction design with an overlayed layer?

Thickness of stage 1 Layers?
Structural Number ?
Modulus of Resilience ?
layer coefficient ?
Other properties?

Additionally, do all layers get effected by the reduction?